# Modifying variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have such an textbox input in an HTML form.

```
<INPUT 
   class="capthca" 
   id = "textfield1"  
   name="textfield1" 
   value="" 
   onBlur="if (this.value == '')
            textfield2.value = ''" 
   onFocus="if (this.value == '')
            this.value = ''" 
   style="
   display:inline-block; 
   height:34px; 
   width:124px;  
   line-height:34px; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   margin-top:10px; 
   margin-bottom:10px; 
   white-space:nowrap; 
   letter-spacing:0px; 
   padding:0 5px;">
```

When I enter an integer variable, I want the textbox which has an id of textfield2 to have a modified variable according to the given variable in textfield1. How can I assign an integer value in this case? I know it is very easy question, but I'm in a bottleneck, I couldn't do this surprisingly.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide a concrete example or two of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please don't use inline anything. Put your styles in CSS, and your javascript in an external script. SO much easier to read

Comment: Hi Ted! I want textbox2 to have the two times value of textbox1. when I assign onBlur="if (this.value == 'aslan')
            textfield2.value = 'kaplan'" 
   onFocus="if (this.value == ''), 
            this.value = ''" and write aslan on textbox1, kaplan appears on textbox2. But I want to try this via integer characters.

Comment: _"But I want to try this via integer characters."_ -- What does that mean? Do you want to enter an integer code in one box and have text appear in a second box based on the value of the integer?

Comment: I think he means he got it working with strings, and now wants to do something similar with integers. That's what I'm assuming at least.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Based on what you said in the comments in your original question... you want to take the value of `textfield1` and make `textfield2` x2 it's value?

**HTML:**

```
<INPUT class="capthca" id = "textfield1"  name="textfield1" value="" onBlur="assignVariable(this.value);">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function assignVariable(value) {

        document.getElementById('textfield2').value = (parseInt(value)) * 2;

}
```

Your question was unclear so I could be wrong about what you want to do. However `parseInt()` will get you an integer as you requested.

**EDIT 2:**

Using strictly inline only hampers yourself, so if you want to do that that's up to you. This should work:

```
 <INPUT 
   class="capthca" 
   id = "textfield1"  
   name="textfield1" 
   value="" 
   onBlur="textfield2.value = (parseInt(this.value)) * 2;"
   style="
   display:inline-block; 
   height:34px; 
   width:124px;  
   line-height:34px; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   margin-top:10px; 
   margin-bottom:10px; 
   white-space:nowrap; 
   letter-spacing:0px; 
   padding:0 5px;">
```

Comment: Because you're using strictly inline, which you shouldn't really be doing. It's probably better practice to learn how to link in an external `.js` file.